# Extracting keys from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, jupyter

### When i Try to run the below code for extracting only name and salary keys and adding it into dictionary d,it is only giving me output {'name': 'Kelly'}.Why is that?

```
 sampleDict = { 
 "name": "Kelly",
 "age":25, 
 "salary": 8000, 
 "city": "New york" }
d={}
for i,j in sampleDict.items():
  if i==("name" or "salary"):
    d[i]=sampleDict[i]
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `i==("name" or "salary")` evaluates `("name" or "salary")` first to `"name"`, then checks for `i=="name"`.

What you should do is to check whether i is in tuple.

```py
  if i in ("name", "salary"):
```

However, a dict comprehension would be more pythonic altogether.

```
d = {k:v for (k,v) in sampleDict.items() if k in ("name", "salary")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write in this way to get both.

```
for i,j in sampleDict.items():
    if i==("name") or i==("salary"):
        d[i]=sampleDict[i]
```

In your code, you have connected two strings with `or`. In python  `"a" or "d"` gives `"a"`.